# jQuery deleting multiple items instead of just one

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table which has buttons when you hover on its rows. There is a delete button that calls a custom confirm dialog; this basically just accepts the callback function that it will perform when the delete is confirmed.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Doe, Jane</td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                25
                                <span class="actions">
                                    <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn-edit" />
                                    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn-delete" />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Doe, John</td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                35
                                <span class="actions">
                                    <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn-edit" />
                                    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn-delete" />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Smith, John</td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                30
                                <span class="actions">
                                    <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn-edit" />
                                    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn-delete" />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>

        <!-- popups -->
        <div id="confirm-delete" class="popup confirm-dialog">
            <h3>Delete</h3>
            <div class="popup-content">
                <p class="confirm-message">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <input id="btn-delete-confirm" type="button" class="button btn-confirm" value="Delete" />
                    <input id="btn-delete-cancel" type="button" class="button btn-close-popup" value="Cancel" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var btnDelete = $('.btn-delete');

    btnDelete.on('click', function(e){
        var popUpId = 'confirm-delete',
                btn = $(e.currentTarget),
                item = $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr'),
                header = 'Delete Item',
                message = 'Are you sure you want to delete ' + item.find('.name').text() + '?';

        customConfirm(popUpId, header, message, function(){ deleteItem(item); });
    });
});

function customConfirm(id, header, message, callback){
    var popUp = $('#' + id),
            btnConfirm = popUp.find('.btn-confirm');

    popUp.find('h3').html(header);
    popUp.find('.confirm-message').html(message);
    popUp.append('<div class="mask"></div>');
    popUp.show();

    btnConfirm.on('click', {popUpId: id, callBack: callback}, confirmClick);

}

function confirmClick(e){
    e.data.callBack();
    closePopUp(e);
}
```

This works fine when I click on the delete button for one item and confirm its deletion. But when I click on the delete button of an item and then cancel it, click on another item's delete button and confirm, both items are deleted. It happens everytime I cancel the deletion of an item. So if I cancel deleting three items and confirm the deletion of the next item, four items will be deleted.

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you :)

PS
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXsEB/7/) link :)

Comment: If you can create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating the issue it will be a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: why don't you try with class attribute to delete particular tr..??

Comment: the function `deleteItem` is not present in your code. Can we see it? Also the code for handling the Cancel button ?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply, was on vacation. Anyway, here's the link for the http://jsfiddle.net/VXsEB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is, the `click` handlers from previous showings of the dialog are still attached to its "Confirm" button.  When you click the button, all the previous handlers are firing, and thus all the previous deletions are being confirmed.

You need to get rid of the previous handlers, either when the dialog is dismissed or as part of showing the dialog.   It's probably simpler, i think, to get rid of it when showing the form; you could simply say `.off('click')` before attaching the new click handler:

```
btnConfirm
    .off('click')
    .on('click', {popUpId: id, callBack: callback}, confirmClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work..
i have modified you js code a bit

http://jsfiddle.net/VKKpe/

changed this

```
 btnConfirm = popUp.find('.btn-confirm');
```

to

```
btnConfirm = $('#btn-delete-confirm');
```

Comment: Hi, @Satish thanks for replying but it doesn't seem to work :)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before and it's not something I would have really thought about, and I'm super glad that I have the opportunity to help someone with it:

binding with .on() *adds* a binding, doesn't replace it.. So it will execute everything you have bound to it in the past.

Simple Solution: `btnConfirm.unbind('click');` right before binding.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/VXsEB/8/

Comment: Hi! Thank you! @cHao 's answer was first so I had to give him the accepted answer. But both work! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help :) I do want to say that you should always award the better quality answer, not the first (I'd say cHao definitely has the better explanation and deserves the accepted answer). We don't want to compromise the quality of SO answers in favor of 'winning a race'. Just thought I'd throw that out there.. :)